# AspectJ pointcut for constructor calls to different classes - identify type of object created

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am using AspectJ and I have defined a pointcut to capture the execution of the constructor methods for a couple of classes as follows:

```
pointcut newobject(): execution(class1.new(..) || class2.new(..) || class3.new(..));
```

then I have

```
after()returning():newobject(){
```

and here I would like to do different things depending on the object just being created being a class1, class2, or class3
if there a way I can refer to the type of the object at this point without having to split the pointcut?

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your pointcut syntax is wrong. You cannot chain multiple method or constructor patterns within  one `execution` pointcut. Instead, you need to chain multiple `execution` pointcuts or, if possible, use jokers like `MyClass*` in order to catch multiple ones. A little example:

```java
pointcut newobject(Object createdObject) :
    (execution(class1.new(..)) || execution(class2.new(..)) || execution(class3.new(..)))
        && this(createdObject);

after(Object createdObject) : newobject(createdObject) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    System.out.println(createdObject);
    System.out.println(createdObject.getClass());
}
```

After binding `this` to a variable name, you can do anything you like with it.